# How to do Rolebinding of PodSecurityPolicy to a group?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, flannel, kubernetes-pod, kube-apiserver

Working on a single node Kubernetes cluster, I wish to apply a [restrictive pod security policy](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/policy/pod-security-policy/#example-policies) to a group of users authenticated via openid. So the sequence of steps are like this.

1. Initialize the cluster, and create the pod security policies.
2. Apply the admission controller `PodSecurityPolicy` in API server (which causes an API server restart)
3. Create a `ClusterRole` and `RoleBinding` for the users.

The authentication of users via openid and fetching their group works good, however, limiting the `PodSecurityPolicy` to this group doesn't work. Example `ClusterRole` and `RoleBinding` given below. If I use `system:authenticated` instead of `mygroup` the policy is picked up for new pod creations.

```yml
kind: ClusterRole
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: psp:restricted
rules:
- apiGroups:
  - extensions
  resources:
  - podsecuritypolicies
  resourceNames:
  - restricted # the psp we are giving access to
  verbs:
  - use
---
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: psp:restricted
subjects:
- kind: Group
  name: mygroup # My group from openid, DOESN'T WORK.
# name: system:authenticated # all authenticated users, WORKS.
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
roleRef:
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: psp:restricted # A references to the role above
apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
```

1. How to do the pod security policy `RoleBinding` to a specific group? Are there any errors in my steps above. I have other `RoleBinding`s on this group which works perfectly fine.
2. A second problem is that [Flannel](https://github.com/coreos/flannel) pod fails to come up, as it seems to pick up the restrictive policy which prevents a volume mount etc. I've read that the [order of the policies matter](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/policy/pod-security-policy/#policy-order), and tried naming the policy with a name that sorts the policy as the last one. If I insert the policies much later, and add `PodSecurityPolicy` admission controller after initializing Flannel, everything seems good. Is there an order we have to follow while inserting policies, admission controllers?

Comment: Were you able to assign a psp  role binding to an OIDC group?

Answer (score 0):

I though I may have had similar issues and found it was a problem with my Role. You can check my question/answer at [Why is my PodSecurityPolicy applied even if I don't have access?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57720681/why-is-my-podsecuritypolicy-applied-even-if-i-dont-have-access)